# Hello, I'm trying to make my first discord bot but when I run it this is what I get. Can someone help me? Thank you

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuGyV.png)

The image above contains my bot code and the error I'm getting while trying to run the script.

It might be easy to solve but I'm new to coding so I'm not really familiar to all of this.

I don't know what to do. Can someone help me ? Thank you

Comment: _"Hello, I'm trying ... when I run it this is what I get. Can someone help me? Thank you"_ Can't you think of a better title? Also: please include errors/code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it looks like your script don't run because you are using a proxy or a VPN ?
I had an error that lookes like this when i used a proxy and this could be it.
Also, check if you don't block SSL requests.

Hope this helped and gave you a clue

P.S: **SSL** stands for **Secure Sockets Layer**, a technology that makes your connection to a website *(or a service)* safe and encrypted. so that any data you provide is exchanged securely with the website *(or the service)*. By default, Python give an error anytime there is a problem with the **SSL certificate**, normally, there is some parameters to add to disable the SSL verification.

Comment: omg thank you so much. So the issue wasn't linked to the vpn but my mac was blocking ssl requests. Thank youuuu